# Overleaf not showing .eps image in IEEE transactions class

Tags: graphics, overleaf, eps

I am trying to insert a .eps image in IEEEtran class using the following source code:

```
begin{figure}[!b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig.eps}
    \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
```

The compilation does not show the image, and show a thumbnail like this

[image]

The file does exist at the path and if I use a file with .jpg format, it compiles successfully. There is something wrong in the way I am inserting the .eps file only.

Please suggest possible solutions.

Thank you.

UPDATE: The draft option is not enabled for class or for graphics. I even tried with `\includegraphics[draft=false]`, but the output is the same.

Comment: You have the `draft` option enabled either as a part of the class options or for `graphicx`. We cannot see what you did because you did not provide a full but minimal example. Now you know why we always ask for full but minimal examples, then we know exactly what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Just change compiler to XeLatex: `Menu`-->`Compilator`-->`XeLatex`

code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{PHOTO.eps}
\caption{}
\label{ris:image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doing this starts giving error: ```Undefined control sequence```

Comment: have you done the same? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler

Comment: Yes exactly the same.

Comment: can you show your source somehow, please?

Comment: why do you have the `dvips` option for `graphicx`, those are generally not needed

Comment: Yes, this is not necessary, just the line was taken from my old file and I just forgot to delete it

Comment: This seems to be working now. I was previously using \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} which was working fine with png and pdf2tex compiler. However, with XeLatex and using \usepackage{graphicx}, it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but for me the issue what that I was using the Fast [draft] compile mode of Overleaf. Switching back to normal compile mode fixed the issue for me!